# Linux Laggy when booting over USB C cable

Tags: linux, boot, usb

I've installed Linux on to a SSD disk and I boot it through a SATA to USB 2.0 cable, which works well.

I've tried to boot from this device using a USB C cable to boost performance but surprisingly the operating system becomes extremely laggy, and freezes up when disk operations are performed.

What might be causing this? Shouldn't running over USB 3.0 be quicker? Is there a way to force linux to use USB 2.0 protocol over the USB C cable during boot?

Comment: A USB C cable doesn’t mean much. Some USB C cables are just charging cables that don’t handle data well or perhaps degrade top USB 1.0/1.1. Others can handle only USB 3.0/3.1/3.2 and such. So the reality is you are assuming that the cable is USB C at top speed but it could just be a, for lack of a better term, crappy cable. Also, there is no such thing as a “SATA to USB 2.0 cable”; that cable has a connector to the SATA that converts data to USB 2.0. So when you say you are using a USB C cable to the drive, what is it connecting to on the drive side?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. This is about more than _cables_. Please list all the SATA-USB bridges you use with their full name. // There is one possibility right away: UASP. It’s a faster alternative to the older Mass Storage class that came with USB 3.0. Linux has unfortunately only limited compatibility. Check the driver in use.

Answer (score 3):

USB-C on it's own doesn't offer any performance gains when it comes to data transfer. Its just a connector shape. In order to get the full SATA bandwidth (6 Gbps) you need to make sure that the cable you are using is rated for a higher bandwidth (10 Gbps/USB3.2 Gen 2).

The other USB spec (3.2 Gen 1) is capped at 5gbps and won't let you use SATA at full capacity.

OTOH, since you mentioned you were getting workable speeds via USB 2.0 (480 Mbps), chances are your USB-C cable is damaged and not even able to let 480 megabits through in a second or is crippled by some interference.

If you are using any port adapter (Like USB A to C or even USB whatever to SATA), make sure it is also able to support the expected bandwidth.

Most of the USB-C adapters and cables intended for power supply are just using USB 2.0 for data transfer and sometimes even not tested for data.

TLDR; try using a cable and/or adapters rated for 10 Gbps